# Don't understand reason for "Incomplete expression; more input is needed" message

Tags: import

I am exporting expressions created in MathType to Mathematica, by copying from the MT screen and using the TraditionalForm[] command. I am getting the "Incomplete expression" error message when I do this with expressions such as:

$${2a{\Omega ^ + }}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahyart1ev3aaatuuDJXwAK1uy0Hwmaerbfv3ySLgzG0uy0Hgip5
% wzamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegqvATv2CG4uz3bIuV1wy
% UbqedmvETj2BSbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2DaebbnrfifHhDYfgiuL2zLj
% hasaacH8srps0lbbf9q8WrFfeuY-Hhbbf9v8qqaqFr0xc9pk0xbba9
% q8WqFfea0-yr0RYxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9q8qqQ8frFve9Fve9Ff
% 0dmeaacaGacmGadaWaaiqacaabaiaafaaakabaaaaaaaaapeqaaiaa
% ikdacaWGHbGaeuyQdC1aaWbaaSqabeaacqGHRaWkaaaaaa!45F7!
$$.

What puzzles me is that TraditionalForm[] has no problem with either

$${2a}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahyart1ev3aaatuuDJXwAK1uy0Hwmaerbfv3ySLgzG0uy0Hgip5
% wzamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegqvATv2CG4uz3bIuV1wy
% UbqedmvETj2BSbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2DaebbnrfifHhDYfgiuL2zLj
% hasaacH8srps0lbbf9q8WrFfeuY-Hhbbf9v8qqaqFr0xc9pk0xbba9
% q8WqFfea0-yr0RYxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9q8qqQ8frFve9Fve9Ff
% 0dmeaacaGacmGadaWaaiqacaabaiaafaaakabaaaaaaaaapeqaaiaa
% ikdacaWGHbaaaa!435A!
$$

or

$${{\Omega ^ + }}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahyart1ev3aaatuuDJXwAK1uy0Hwmaerbfv3ySLgzG0uy0Hgip5
% wzamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegqvATv2CG4uz3bIuV1wy
% UbqedmvETj2BSbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2DaebbnrfifHhDYfgiuL2zLj
% hasaacH8srps0lbbf9q8WrFfeuY-Hhbbf9v8qqaqFr0xc9pk0xbba9
% q8WqFfea0-yr0RYxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9q8qqQ8frFve9Fve9Ff
% 0dmeaacaGacmGadaWaaiqacaabaiaafaaakabaaaaaaaaapeqaaiab
% fM6axnaaCaaaleqabaGaey4kaScaaaaa!4455!
$$

when those are entered separately.

Can someone 1) explain why I'm getting this error (and what more input it wants), and 2) tell me what documentation I should have looked at in order to figure this out myself?

Thank you,

-Alan

Comment: An answer here, https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/571131, states, "Note that such imported formula not necessarily represent a valid Mathematica formula." What does the menu comand Cell > Show Expression show for the cell with the bad input?

Comment: Thank you Michael E2 for your reply. I previously found the Community groups discussion you flagged. In saying "...such imported formula not necessarily represent,,,", the commenter was referring specifically to simply cutting from MT and pasting into Mathematica. I started out doing exactly that (cutting and pasting) and found my way to using TraditionalForm[].

Comment: Michael E2 - finger slipped, hadn't finished my message. Cell -> Show Expression yield this:Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  TagBox[
   RowBox[{"2", "a", 
    SuperscriptBox["\[CapitalOmega]", "\[Minus]"]}],
   "MathMLPresentationTag",
   AutoDelete->True], TraditionalForm]], "Input"]  I'm afraid I don't know what this means - can you interpret it for me? Thank you.

Comment: The `SuperscriptBox` is interpreted as `Power` and the second argument, which is just a minus sign, needs to be a complete expression (in the mysterious box form). That's the source of the syntax error. I don't know how to fix it. I don't know if Mathematica has a character that looks like a minus sign that is not interpreted as subtraction. You can replace the `"\[Minus]"` by `"\"\<-\>\""` but it's not perfect. (Input form has quotes, output form looks ok).

Comment: @MichaelE2, I think you can just replace it with "-". In this case, it won't be interpreted as `Power`, but as `SuperMinus`.

Comment: @Domen Thanks, I couldn't recall the name of `SuperMinus` or if I only imagined it. It's not clear to me how to use it in the OP's workflow. But maybe a little bit of hand entry is ok.

Comment: See if executing this directly under the bad cell fixes it: `NotebookWrite[PreviousCell[], NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]] /. TagBox[e_, "MathMLPresentationTag", ___] :> e /. "\[Minus]" -> "-"]` -- might have to do something different for the + superscript. Or other superscripts.

Comment: Thanks so much Michael E2 and Donen! Replacing "\[Minus]" by "-" worked, although the first result was a "HoldComplete" on the expression, and I had to ReleaseHold. Now:  I have many expressions like this in my MathType code - do I have to go through this every time, or will the fix just applied now work on all the instances of the expression?